# Google firebase randomly crashes on iOS at FIRInstanceID tokenWithAuthorizedEntity

Tags: c++, ios, firebase, crash, ios9

I'm having a problem with random firebase crash. It happens rarely and at random so i cant catch it on debugger. All I have is [this stack trace from fabric crashlytics.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiGZm.png)

Firebase app is created using " ::firebase::App::Create() " and it seams that crash happens there.
I'm using firebase c++ SDK v3.1.2, and iOS framework v3.14.0, on ios 9.3.4.

If anyone have any ideas, I would like to hear them :)

Comment: Do you have GoogleService-Info.plist file set in your project ?

Comment: @IvanAndrosenko Yep.